# FileSystemDirectories suggestion in RadDropDownList (Telerik)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

Windows form combo box control has a nice feature to show assigned value when drop down list is expanded and suggest folders if text is typed in control itself (AutoCompleteSource should be set to FileSystemDirectories). Telerik's RadDropDownList (equivalent control for combobox) doesin't seem to work in a same way.

ComboBox initialization:

```
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories;
```

RadDropDownList initialization:

```
this.radDropDownList.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
this.radDropDownList.AutoCompleteDataSource = AutoCompleteSource.FileSystemDirectories;
```

Problem is that Teleriks control does not suggest or show any kind of directories same as Microsoft's control does. If I remove `AutoCompleteDataSource` assignment row, control suggests values from list assingned in `DataSource` property.

I am using Telerik's WinForm type controls.

Am I doing something wrong, or Telerik's drop down list does not have functionality as Microsoft's does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadDropDownList works only with the specified AutoCompleteDataSource and will complete just items that exist in it. You can produce a data source with the desired items and assign it to the control.